# How to append to the same variable with augeas run via puppet?

Tags: puppet, augeas

I have the following resource declaration to set the `setenv.sh` file via augeas in puppet.

```
augeas {'test':
    lens    => 'Properties.lns',
    incl    => '/tmp/setenv.sh',
    changes => "set CATALINA_OPTS \" $CATALINA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m \"",
}
```

I have run into a few issues with the above.

1. The file basically appends configs to the `CATALINA_OPTS` variable which means when I run augeas it removes all instances of that variable and replaces it with my change. How can I achieve the following?

   ```
   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/appdynamics/appagent/javaagent.jar"
   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m"
   ```
2. An attempt to run the above fails due to the quotes. The debug output shows:

   ```
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files/tmp/setenv.sh/CATALINA_OPTS", "  -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m "]
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): Put failed on one or more files, output from /augeas//error:
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/tmp/setenv.sh/error = put_failed
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/tmp/setenv.sh/error/path = /files/tmp/setenv.sh
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/tmp/setenv.sh/error/lens = /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/properties.aug:50.25-.100:
   Debug: Augeas[test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/tmp/setenv.sh/error/message = Malformed child node 'CATALINA_OPTS'
   ```

How can I have the change use double quotes in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to append lines to a file, try using file_line resource instead of augeas, for example:

```
file_line { 'line1':
  path => '/tmp/setenv.sh',
  line => 'CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/appdynamics/appagent/javaagent.jar"',
}

file_line { 'line2':
  path => '/tmp/setenv.sh',
  line => 'CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m"',
}
```

To avoid issues with doublequotes, just singlequote the whole file line. If you want to add line to a specific place in the file, you can use the 'after' property.

file_line is available in 'puppetlabs/stdlib' module.

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered that this needs to be added mid-file. I believe `file_line` appends to the end of the line correct?

Comment: My answers states: 'if you want to add line to a specific place in the file....'. So, try the 'after => ' param.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to impact on the last `CATALINA_OPTS` variable, you need to specify it:

```
augeas {'test':
    lens    => 'Properties.lns',
    incl    => '/tmp/setenv.sh',
    changes => "set CATALINA_OPTS[last()] \" $CATALINA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m \"",
}
```

You could use `[2]` instead of `[last()]`, but at least the latter one ensures it's the last occurrence of the variable in the file.